# Using UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext to optimize layout calculations during inserts, deletes and moves

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've implemented a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` for my `UICollectionView` and also a custom `UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext` hoping to get good performance.

In my first use case, I have floating headers and during scrolling I only invalidate the headers that need to slide.

I do this as follows:

- I return `YES` from `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:`.
- When my `invalidationContextForBoundsChange:` method gets called I add stale headers to the context by calling `invalidateSupplementaryElementsOfKind:atIndexPaths:`.
- When `invalidateLayoutWithContext:` gets called I don't really need to do anything because invalidating the header was enough to get the following **key thing to happen**: `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath:` gets called instead of everything starting over with `prepareLayout`.

This works great.

My first question is: What about this scenario suppressed the `prepareLayout` sequence? At first I thought that adding any data to the context (in this case the index paths of stale supplementaries) was enough for Apple to presume I knew what I was doing (iOS8-wise) and not call `prepareLayout`. I know longer believe that as you'll see below.

My second use case: In practice, my data source almost always adds items only at the end. And for my layout algorithm, that means that the layout of earlier (indexPath-wise) items don't go invalid with new data. I don't want to spend time recomputing potentially large numbers of layout attributes that I don't need to. So I need to do "*the right thing*" when the client code calls say:

```
[collection insertItemsAtIndexPaths: newIndices];
```

by noting what the earliest indexPath in `newIndices` is and recompute my layout starting from there.  Almost always, `newIndices` starts at the very end and no existing cells go stale--so only attributes for the new cells should be asked of my layout object by Apple.

But note, there is no analogous method to `invalidationContextForBoundsChange:` for insert/delete/move calls. So I have no way to preconfigure my context with say what indices are coming and going.

So inside the call to `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` this is what happens:

- My context object gets -init'ed. This happens early--before `invalidateLayout` is called. At init time, `self.invalidateEverything` and `self.invalidateDataSourceCounts` are (NO,NO) (and they're readonly).
- Next my `invalidateLayoutWithContext:` is called now with `invalidateDataSourceCounts` set to `YES`--Apple telling me only that my counts are stale. That's useless as that doesn't tell me anything about where to restart my layout calculations. But this is my first (and only chance) to notice something or to do something.
- Next my `prepareLayout` gets called--**Grrr!** I don't want to start over. I don't want `prepareLayout` called--or at least I need to stash some info before it's called so I don't overwork. But my only chance was in `invalidateLayoutWithContext:` and I don't know anything at the time this was called (remember there is nothing similar to `invalidationContextForBoundsChange:`). Further `invalidateDataSourceCounts==YES` is useless.

I tried to `invalidateItemsAtIndexPaths:` any old cell in view inside `invalidateLayoutWithContext:` to test if that's enough to prevent a call to `prepareLayout` (in case I did somehow figure out which cells to inval). No go--`prepareLayout` was still called. So second question: Is `invalidateLayoutWithContext:` too late to call things like `invalidateItemsAtIndexPaths:` for Apple to react?

Now to add insult to injury, I notice in the debugger that at `invalidateLayoutWithContext:` time my context has a private ivar named `_updateItems` that has all the info I need (at the only time I get a chance to use it). But there is no getter for this ivar. These `UICollectionViewUpdateItem` entries are delivered only when my `prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:` method gets called. But guess when this gets called--after `prepareLayout` and friends (`collectionViewContentSize` and `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`).

I'm either missing something key or these APIs are broken. Certainly I should be able to add a cell at the end of my layout efficiently. Was I supposed to notice the `invalidateDataSourceCounts==YES` and just warn my `prepareLayout` implementation--"Sorry you got called, don't do anything yet. I'll try to call you again later myself after I know what to do."

Or was the *client* code supposed to somehow create an instance of my context and configure it *before* calling `[collection insertItemsAtIndexPaths: newIndices]`? But then how are clients suppose to hand this context down inside the `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` call? Further are clients really supposed to be exposed to this implementation detail?

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this? Encountering the exact same problem, seems like a bug in what order stuff is called in the layout objects :(